# Where will this struct be stored and why?

Tags: c#, struct

```cs
void Test()
{
    Test.Instance.a++;
    Console.WriteLine("Test:" + Test.Instance.a);
}

struct Test
{
    public static Test Instance  = new();
    public int a;
}
```

Will the Test.Instance object be stored on heap or on stack and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They can't be stored on the stack as their is no stack frame associated with static data.

And according to Jon Skeet's [blog](https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/memory.html), *"Every static variable is stored on the heap."*